# Handle empty JSON using ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-api, alamofire

I was wondering how to handle empty response from JSON response?

The Alamofire Call

```
func getBooksWith(author: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Book]>) -> Void) {
    let mainUrl = "\(ApiUrl.baseUrl)\(ApiUrl.endPoint)\(author)"
    print(mainUrl)
    guard let url = URL(string: mainUrl) else { return }
    Alamofire.request(url).responseArray(keyPath:"items") { (response:
        DataResponse<[Book]>) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let books = response.result.value {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.Succes(books))
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.Error(error.localizedDescription))
        }
    }
}
```

So functions returns us an array of Books, but some JSON data is missing, for example not all objects have imgUrl, or description

```
class Book: Mappable {

var title: String?
var authors: [String]?
var publishedDate: String?
var description: String?
var imgUrl: [String: AnyObject]?
var publisher: String?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    publisher <- map["volumeInfo.publisher"] 
    title <- map["volumeInfo.title"]
    publishedDate <- map["volumeInfo.publishedDate"]
    description <- map["volumeInfo.description"]
    authors <- map["volumeInfo.authors"]
    imgUrl <- map["volumeInfo.imageLinks"]
    }
}
```

So what i did is in VC where I call updateUI func

```
func updateUI() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.authorLabel.text = self.book?.authors?[0] ?? "Woops! No info!"
        self.publisherLabel.text = self.book?.publisher ?? "Woops! No info!"
        self.yearLabel.text = self.book?.publishedDate ?? "Woops! No info!"
        self.detailsLabel.text = self.book?.description ?? "Woops! No info!"
        guard let stringurl = self.book?.imgUrl?["thumbnail"] as? String else { return }
        guard let url = URL(string: stringurl) else { return }
        self.bookImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "loadingImg"))
    }
}
```

simply used ??, but can I use it in any other, better way?
For example how can I display alert that some of the data is missing?

Comment: It depends on what you actually want to display in case of *No Info*

Comment: @vadian not getting to the point like always :) edited question, btw.. what are you doing, when json is not complete?

Comment: Programming is a very precise subject. For example regarding the edited question: There is a significant difference between *not all data were downloaded properly*  which indicates a connection error and *some of the downloaded dictionaries don't contain some keys*

Comment: @vadian made an edit one more time, just to make it more precise :)

Comment: Make a boolean variable called haveAllData and set it to true. Walk through all the elements and if any required elements are missing set the variable to false.  At the end, if haveAllData is false, show an alert.